'invoke-pnpsitetemplate : object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
We are trying to apply pnp-template by following this article. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/applying-pnp-templates
I have downloaded the 'theperspectivepnp' from the site and created a 'Mysite' in my tenant. After that I tried the below command
Connect-PnPOnline https://testonlinesite-admin.sharepoint.com/
Invoke-PnPSiteTemplate -Path c:\temp\theperspective.pnp -Parameters @{"SiteUrl"="/sites/Mysite"}

I am getting a below error
'invoke-pnpsitetemplate : object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
Please advise on this.

Seeing that this problem has been solved on other platforms, I put the post here so that people who encounter similar problems can see it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1669382/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-obje
